# Spring - Use applicationContext from .jar file added as a dependency

Tags: java, spring, applicationcontext

Imagine a situation where there are 2 independent modules - Module A and B. Both of them are constructed using Spring. Each of them have its own applicationContext - Module A works with applicationContextA and B - applicationContextB.
Module A contains facade class - defined in a bean moduleAFacade - that provides some functionality of Module A. Module B needs to access the functionality of Module A. 
Let's have Module A added as a .jar dependency in the module B.
There is this construction in applicationContextB:

```xml
<bean id="moduleBBeanUsingModuleAfacade" class="com.example.moduleB">
    <property name="moduleAFacadeObject" ref="moduleAFacade" />
</bean>
```

But applicationContext of Module A is not accessible from Module B's appContext directly. I need to use something like

```xml
<import resource="classpath*:moduleAApplicationContext.xml" />
```

Are there any other methods to access application contexts of .jar files added to the project as dependency?
Are there some best practises how to accomplish the task?

Comment: What you're doing seems fine, what's the problem?

Comment: Well, it seems to me (and my co-workers) that such a method violates decoupling and clarity of Spring-oriented approach. Let's say there are 5 external libraries added to module B - it means there will be 5 import statements in the module B's appContext. Seems like code repetition to me...
The question is - Isn't there any other approach to "merge" application contexts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a configuration file in module A

```
package you.organisation.moduleA.config;
@Configuration
@ImportResource("classpath:path/to/applicationContextA.xml")
public class ModuleAConfig implements Serializable {

}
```

and in the module B context file, you can access module A beans

```xml
<context:component-scan base-package="you.organisation.*.config" />
```

If you want to use Module B config files, tou do the same

```
package you.organisation.moduleB.config;
@Configuration
@ImportResource("classpath:path/to/applicationContextB.xml")
public class ModuleBConfig implements Serializable {

}
```

and in the module that will use it

```xml
<context:component-scan base-package="you.organisation.*.config" />
```

About best practices you must be careful when using wildcards, please have a [look to the section 4.7.2.2](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/resources.html)

Comment: Thank you Centonni - your answer was exactly the thing I needed to learn.

Comment: Awesome to hear it helped you! :)